# Generate random images with different percentages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a project which requires me to generate an amount (let's say 50) random images from a gallery, with some having a smaller chance of being generated than others. The script needs to be fast and elegant.

I currently have the following HTML:

```
<div className="item-picture">
  <img class="random-img" src="" />
</div>
<div className="item-picture">
  <img class="random-img" src="" />
</div>
<div className="item-picture">
  <img class="random-img" src="" />
</div>
<div className="item-picture">
  <img class="random-img" src="" />
</div>
```

and the following javascript:

```
function randomImg(){
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
var imgName = "img_" + randomNumber + ".png";
document.getElementByClassName("random-img").src= "img" + "/" + imgName ;
}
```

However, this script doesn't allow me to generate multiple images, and I'm not able to set any %. I am a rookie at javascript and would love to get some help.

I am building this application with React.JS and jQuery is also allowed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, this code can generate 50 images but i didn't get what you wanted from the `%` :

```
// use container for HTML tags
<div id="container">
</div>
<script>

    function randomImg(){
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
        var imgName = "img_" + randomNumber + ".png";
        for (let i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
            let src = "img" + "/" + imgName ;
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += `<img class="random-img" src=${src} />`
        }
    }

</script>
```

UPDATE:

```
function randomImg(){
        let collection = {}
        for (let i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
            var imgName = "img_" + randomNumber + ".png";
            let src = "img" + "/" + imgName ;
            if (!collection[randomNumber]) {
                collection[randomNumber] = 1; // this will be for count the appearances of the img
            } else {
                collection[randomNumber] += 1; 
            }
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += `<img class="random-img" src=${src} /><span class=${randomNumber} ></span>`
        }
        for (randomNumber in collection) {
            percent = collection[randomNumber] / 50
            /*
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += ` ${randomNumber} Appeared: ${percent}`
            */
        }
    }
```

This will be added at the end of the container div like this :

`1 Appeared: 0.26 2 Appeared: 0.24 3 Appeared: 0.26 4 Appeared: 0.22`

if you want it to be added to each image you can replace the commented line with this code:

```
  $(`.${randomNumber}`).map(
                function () {
                    this.innerHTML += ` ${randomNumber} Appeared: ${percent}`
                }
            )
```

**UPDATE**: to add all at once:

```
function randomImg(){
        let all = []
        let collection = {}
        for (let i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
            var imgName = "img_" + randomNumber + ".png";
            let src = "img" + "/" + imgName ;
            all.push([src, randomNumber])
            if (!collection[randomNumber]) {
                collection[randomNumber] = 1; // this will be for count the appearances of the img
            } else {
                collection[randomNumber] += 1; 
            }
        }
        for (image of all) {
            src = image[0]
            randomNumber = image[1]
            percent = collection[randomNumber] / 50
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += `<img class="random-img" src=${src} /><span> Appeared: ${percent}</span>`
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to make an array (I think?) with the percentages of certain images to be shown. So for example I output 10 div's with 2 images, and image 1 has a chance of 70%, then 7 out of 10 images would be image 1.

Comment: This worked however I want the images to be generated and used once, right now the images update to other images after 2 seconds.